# How to get Loess function for my data in R?

Tags: r, plot, nonlinear-functions

I have a some data and I draw them on a plot, using R.
After that, I draw the loess function about that data.
Here is the code:

```
data <- read.table("D:/data.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",", na.strings="NA", dec=".", strip.white=TRUE)
ur <- subset(data, select = c(users,responseTime))
ur <- ur[with(ur, order(users, responseTime)), ]

plot(ur, xlab="Users", ylab="Response Time (ms)")
lines(ur)
loess_fit <- loess(responseTime ~ users, ur)
lines(ur$users, predict(loess_fit), col = "blue")
```

Here's my plot's image:
[image: http://tinypic.com/r/2ziqa2x/8]

How can I get the function of this regression?
For example: responseTime = 68 + 45 * users.

Thanks.

Comment: There is no simple "loess function". It's a local piecewise fit. If you use `loess` you are implicitly saying "I don't have any theory about the form of the result".

Comment: What I want, is to create a function that I could predict the responseTime when i know how many users I have. Maybe it is wrong to use loess, but it looks like fitting to my data.

Comment: Well `loess` is fitting to data, but maybe what you want is a polynomial or spline fit?

Comment: Do you know how can R help me to create that function, to predict the response time?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `loess_fit` object from your code to predict the response time. If you want to estimate the average response time for 230 users, you could do:

```
predict(loess_fit, newdata=data.frame(users=230))
```

Here is an interesting [blog post](http://blog.optimizely.com/2013/12/11/why-cdn-balancing/) on this subject.

EDIT: If you want to make predictions for values outside your data, you need a theory or further assumptions. The most simple assumption would be a linear fit,

```
lm_fit <- lm(responseTime ~ users, data=ur)
predict(lm_fit, newdata=data.frame(users=400))
```

However, your data may show heteroscedacity (non-constant variance) and may show non-normal residuals. You might want to check if that is the case. If it is, then a robust linear fitting procedure such as `rlm` from the package `MASS`, or a generalized linear model `glm` might be worth a try. I am not an expert for that, maybe someone else or at [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) can provide better help.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This work for users until 250 that I have data. If I want more? for example 400 users.

Answer (score 0):

The `loess.demo` function in the TeachingDemos package shows the logic underlying the loess fit.  This can help you understand what is going on and why there is not a simple prediction function.  However, for predicting, there is a `predict` function that works with loess fits to create the prediction.  You can also find the linear equation that will predict for a specific value of x (but it will be different for each value of x you may want to predict for).